# Inferring Inverse Property in Protege

Tags: ontology, protege, inference

I have created the relationship `A 'is functional parent of' B` and defined `'has functional parent'` as the inverse of `'is functional parent of'`. `'A'` and `'B'` are both subclasses of `'chemical entity'`.

I want Protege to infer `B 'has functional parent' A`. The query `'has functional parent' some A` fails.

#### Error #1: Not understanding open world

I realized that `some` implies that not all `B` have the relationship `'has functional parent'` with `'A'`. **However, the query `'chemical entity' and 'has functional parent'` still fails.**

My ontology has no instances. I was hoping the query wound find subclasses.

#### Turtle File

```
@prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/michaelchary/ontologies/2020/8/untitled-ontology-10#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.semanticweb.org/michaelchary/ontologies/2020/8/untitled-ontology-10> .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/michaelchary/ontologies/2020/8/untitled-ontology-10> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

#################################################################
#    Object Properties
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/michaelchary/ontologies/2020/8/untitled-ontology-10#hasFunctionalParent
:hasFunctionalParent rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
                     owl:inverseOf :isFunctionalParentOf .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/michaelchary/ontologies/2020/8/untitled-ontology-10#isFunctionalParentOf
:isFunctionalParentOf rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .


#################################################################
#    Classes
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/michaelchary/ontologies/2020/8/untitled-ontology-10#A
:A rdf:type owl:Class ;
   rdfs:subClassOf :Z ,
                   [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                     owl:onProperty :isFunctionalParentOf ;
                     owl:someValuesFrom :B
                   ] .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/michaelchary/ontologies/2020/8/untitled-ontology-10#B
:B rdf:type owl:Class ;
   rdfs:subClassOf :Z .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/michaelchary/ontologies/2020/8/untitled-ontology-10#Z
:Z rdf:type owl:Class .


###  Generated by the OWL API (version 4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi
```

Comment: Please add a minimal ontology illustrating the problem you experience.

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse I added a minimal ontology in Turtle syntax.

Comment: This .ttl file give an error when I try to open it in Protege. Please provide the exact file you used in Protege.

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse uploaded the exact TTL file from Protege

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the axioms you stated in your ontology, there is absolutely nothing from which the reasoner can derive that `B hasFunctionalParent A`.

To understand why this is the case, it is helpful to think in terms of individuals even though your ontology does not include any explicit individuals. When the reasoner runs, it tries to generate a model based on the axioms in the ontology. A model consists of generated individuals that adheres to the axioms of your ontology.

For illustration purposes, let us assume the universe of individuals consists of the following numbers:

Domain = `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`,

`Z = {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7}`,

`A = {5, 7}` and

`B = {2, 3, 6}`

Then you have an object property `hasFunctionalParent` with its inverse. For short I will refer to `hasFunctionalParent` as `R` and its inverse as `invR`. What does `R` and `invR` mean? It basically states that when 2 individuals in our domain are related via `R`, they are also related via `invR`. That is, if we have `R(1, 2)`, then `invR(2, 1)` also hold.

Stating that `A subClassOf  invR some B` implies that each individual of `A` is related via `invR` to at least 1 individual of `B`. Thus, if we have `invR(5, 2)` and `invR(7, 3)`, we also will have `R(2, 5)` and `R(3, 7)`. However, this says *nothing* about the class `B` in general. It is completely possible that `R(6, 0)` holds. Therefore the reasoner cannot infer that `B hasFunctionalParent A`.

To get `B` and `Z` for the query "find the super classes of  `hasFunctionalParent some B`" (that means "superclasses" must be ticked in Protege when doing the query) you have to state that `isFunctionalParentOf` has domain `A` and range `B`. This states that whenever 2 individuals `x` and `y` are related via `isFunctionalParentOf`, we can assume `x` is an instance of `A` and `y` is an instance of `B`.

Lastly, you will note that you will need to use the DL query tab in Protege to get to this inference. In particular it is not shown as part of the inferences after reasoning. Why is that? That is because Protege only shows inferences of *named* classes. `hasFunctionalParent some B` is an anonymous class, therefore this inference is not shown. A trick to make this show in Protege is to add an arbitrary concept say `X` that you set as equivalent to `hasFunctionalParent some B`. If you now run the reasoner, Protege will infer that `X subClassOf B`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see my error, but the spirit of my original question remains. What if there are three classes A,B,C and I want to infer invR(B,A) and invR(B,C) from R(A,B) and R(B,C)? If I set the domain of R to be the intersection of {A,B}, doesn't that lose the specificity of the relationship?

Comment: Yes, it will loose the specificity. The only way to maintain it is the introduce a new object property, say invS and S, with the appropriate range. Without that the reasoner simply does not have sufficient information to make inferences you require.

Comment: BTW, you want the union of {A,B} rather than the intersection.